# Creating new process with Lua interpreater, failures in passing argumets

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, process, lua

I need help with passing arguments in CreateProcess() //Windows

I want to:

```
BOOL status = CreateProcess(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Lua\\lua52.exe", 
NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

But with passing some arguments....

Lua interpreater accepts file with lua-scripts, so I have prepared it and want to do:

```
lua52 C:\1.lua
```

for example...

I have the path of some lua-script and want the interpreater of Lua to interpreate it and than get the result of program on Lua from Created process.

I have tried in some ways to do it, but no success.

Comment: Is your problem running the lua script or getting the result? What exactly have you tried, and how had it failed? In general, you can either pass the script file as the second argument, or pass NULL to the first, and both process name and script path to the as the second (surrounding the process path with double quotes to escape the spaces). What happens if you do that?

Comment: @eran with lua-script all is normal, with getting result the problem I have

Comment: @eran Exactly: 1). I have file on FS ( 1.lua ) , it contains lua-script 2). I have Lua-interpreater 3). I want to launch Lua-interpreater and give the script to it, then I want to get the result of script 4). That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static STARTUPINFO si;
static PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

int main ()
{
    ZeroMemory (&si, sizeof si);
    ZeroMemory (&pi, sizeof pi);

    si.cb = sizeof si;

    wсhar_t command [] = L"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Lua\\lua52.exe\" C:\\1.lua";

    BOOL status = CreateProcess (0, command, 0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget about:

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the
>   contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer
>   to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If
>   this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access
>   violation.